# facebook fanpage my application permissions likes users

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-like

myname is tolga 
i have  problem :(

i have facebook aplication. this users likes fan page

sample

https://api.facebook.com/method/stream.addLike?uid=".$user."&post_id=".$post."&access_token=".$tokken."&format=json

like this user post id.
access_token those who have it automatically like it

i want to.like last visit, my page .

thanks. waiting for help :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rest API is deprecated. See:   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/

I would suggest recoding this with the newer API and see if your issue still exists.

Comment: I think he understood my English is bad, sorry.
I want to endear fan page

Comment: auto LİKEs users my app access token

Comment: Users liked my page in my application?

Comment: No, your page object cannot be liked that way for security purposes. There are very specific items that can be liked via the API. However there's other objects that can be liked such as a `post`, a `photo`, a `video`, etc. For Facebook, Likes is a user initiated thing and auto page likes is not allowed. So that's why you must use the like plugin.

Comment: thank you DMCS up up you true saysing. subscribe no button for api ?

Comment: Please try the new API. If after using the new API and you're still having issues, please start a new question as this conversation has become overrun with followup after followup question.  This is not fair to the users of Stackoverflow for so many followups.